# update in database in JDO using google app engine ..it didn't work?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, persistence, jdo

i need to update some entry in my data base using jdo in java and i use google app engine 
although i write the code correctly the update didn't work with me ??
this is my code

```
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GoUpdate extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {

        String msg = req.getParameter("msg");
        String oldname = req.getParameter("nameold");
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        String o = req.getParameter("salary");
        int salary = Integer.parseInt(o);
        String datestring = req.getParameter("date");
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(datestring);// 10-10-2010
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        Query query = pm.newQuery(User.class, "name == nameParam");

        query.declareParameters("String nameParam");

        List<User> list = (List<User>) query.execute(oldname);

        try {
            for (User obj : list) {

                 {


                obj.name = name;
                obj.salary = salary;
                obj.date = date;
                req.setAttribute("msg1", msg);
                pm.makePersistent(obj);

            }
        } finally {

            pm.close();
            resp.getWriter().println(">>>>>>>>>>");
        }

        RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("view");

        try {

            view.forward(req, resp);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // resp.sendRedirect("view");

    }
```

Comment: You are missing the JDO transaction, in JDO you can't do any modification out of a transaction scope.

Comment: i have added the transaction begin and commit but the problem still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to update an object with JDO is to fetch the object, then modify it while the PersistenceManager that returned the object is still open. Changes are persisted when the PersistenceManager is closed. For example:

```
public void updateUserTitle(User user, String newTitle) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        User e = pm.getObjectById(User.class, user.getId());

            e.setTitle(newTitle);
        } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: it is another way to update the user object
, in my project am sure that the program enter the for loop and the object been updated !!!
but my problem still on datastore didn't update ::

Answer (score 0):

By "didn't work" I'm assuming it didn't update your datastore as opposed to you got an error. 
If so, you need to begin and commit a JDO transaction if want to make updates to the datastore via this API:

```
    pm.currentTransaction().begin(); // <<<
    for (User obj : list) {
        obj.name = name;
        obj.salary = salary;
        obj.date = date;
        req.setAttribute("msg1", msg);
        pm.makePersistent(obj);
    }
    pm.currentTransaction().commit(); // <<<
```

Comment: The code looks correct, so you'll need to post your config file as well as a log output of this code with datanucleus loggers set to FINE/DEBUG for us to be able to help you further on this...

Comment: how can i get the log file for web page ?